# LaTex error: missing \endcsname inserted. Cannot compile

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files, output

while editing the citations in a chapter of my thesis I got dozens of errors like the following and can't compile the file to a pdf anymore:

```
*Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.420 ...dre_left_2007}{nyt/global//global/global}
                                                  
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.*
```

It appears there is something wrong with the citation or the output.aux file. I tried clearing the cache, but it didn't help.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be about? I would appreciate any tips!
This is my .tex file:

```
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english,
%ngerman,
onehalfspacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
\headsepline  % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true,
openany,
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\makeatletter
%\let\degree\relax
%\makeatother
\usepackage{array} %for tables
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
%\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
%\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

%\addto\extrasenglish{\def\subfigurename{Figure}}
%\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{nonumber}{#1:}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=nonumber}

%\captionsetup{
 % textfont=12pt,
 %justification=centerfirst;%raggedright,
 % singlelinecheck=false
%}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{References0111.bib} % The filename of the bibliography
\setlength\bibnamesep{1.5\itemsep}
%\setlength{\bibsep}{5pt}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    %outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    outer=3cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\myname}{xxx}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{xxx}
\newcommand{\firstsupervisor}{xxx}
\newcommand{\cosupervisor}{xxx}
\newcommand{\matrikelnummer}{xxx}
\newcommand{\thesis}{Thesis for Attaining the Academic Grade}
\newcommand{\Master}{xxx)}
\newcommand{\inwhat}{in}
\newcommand{\program}{xxx}
\newcommand{\uni}{xxx}
\newcommand{\submission}{}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Title Page                                                                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{large}
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{5cm} 

\makebox[9.5em][r]{\includegraphics[width=15cm]{logos.png}}
% for me it worked converting all eps to pdf using epstopdf
%\makebox[4cm][c]{UniLogo.pdf}  
%\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
    \mbox{}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE \mytitle}\\
      %{\huge huge font size}
      \vfill
      by \\
      \vfill
      {\Large \myname}\\
      \vfill
      \vfill
      {\normalsize \thesis}\\[0.2in]
      {\Large \Master} \\
      {\normalsize \inwhat} \\[0.1in]
      {\Large \program} \\
      \vfill
      {\normalsize \firstsupervisor}\\
      {\normalsize \cosupervisor}\\
      {\normalsize \submission}\\
      \vspace{.2in}
      \mbox{}
   \end{center}
   \end{large}
   \end{titlepage}
  
  
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Abstract                                               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}  % this is the first counted page
 \ohead*{}
\ihead*{}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\chapter*{Abstract\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}}
 % not longer than 150 words for BSc theses and MSc theses!
 
%write here


  
  
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\newpage
%\chapter*{Acknowledgements\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)


\end{abbreviations}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0in}{20pt}

\ohead*{}
\ihead*{}
\chead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}



% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\include{Chapters/Methods} 
\include{Chapters/Results}
\include{Chapters/Discussion} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


\appendix

%\appendixname{Appendix}
% Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices
% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices
\renewcommand\appendixname{}

\chapter{Appendix} 
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\nocite{*}
%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Affirmation Statement/Eidesstattliche Erklärung                                                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % no footnotes, no heads, no page numbers
    \mbox{}
      \vfill
      {\Large Eidesstattliche Erklärung\\} 
      \vfill
      Hiermit erkläre ich, \myname, die vorliegende Arbeit \textit{\mytitle} selbständig verfasst zu haben und keine anderen Quellen oder Hilfsmittel als die angegebenen verwendet zu haben. 
       \vfill 
        \vfill
        $\overline{\textrm{\myname, \matrikelnummer}}$
      \vfill
      \vfill
      \vfill
      {\Large Affirmation Statement\\} 
      \vfill
      I, \myname, hereby affirm that I composed the work at hand, entitled \textit{\mytitle}, autonomously and that I did not use any other resources or auxiliary means than the ones stated. 
            \vfill 
        \vfill
        $\overline{\textrm{\myname, \matrikelnummer}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have posted a _lot_ of code but none of it is any use to anyone trying to help as it includes files we do not have and does not reproduce the problem that you are asking about. Start with a copy of your project and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem, then edit the question to include a small but complete self contained document that generates the error.

Comment: It looks like your problem is around line 420 when you do something regarding `unhbox` to `nyt/global/global/global`.  But since your code is 288 lines long and doesn't contain those phrases anywhere (but does include four other chapters), that's the extent of the help that we can offer.

Comment: start by looking at a bib entry with a key that ends with `dre_left_2007`

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question and thanks for your effort! I solved it now. The errors were due to the underscore package I loaded which interfered with biblatex.